# Get a value from another row and add to the current row based on a certain info included in the current row - for the entire dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Although I'm aware of how to get info of specific rows based on some data (and in particular of [this rock-solid answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17071908/5452001) about that), I'm struggling to figure out the best way of doing this for the entire dataframe, *hopefully without having to loop through it*.

I have records of "buy" and "sell" transactions, all in the same df. What triggered each "buy" transaction is recorded in the respective row where the "buy" transaction is saved. I need to copy that information to the equivalent "sell" transactions. The sell transaction rows contain the "ID" of the "buy" transactions, which are the index of the df.

```
     Type   Trigger   Buy ID
ID   
11   buy     AA       ---
12   buy     BB       ---
13   sell    ---      11
14   sell    ---      12
```

So I want to create a new column (e.g. "BuyTrigger") and add the trigger from the "buy" transaction to the "sell" rows. What I have tried (among others):

```
df = data[data["Type"] == "sell"]
df["BuyTrigger"] = data.loc[df["Buy order ID"]]["Trigger"]
```

Above, I've created a copy of a slice of the data with the sell transactions only to make the process faster. Buy that is returning all NANs for "Buy Trigger".

And just to make it super clear: there are two dataframes. DATA contains all records; DF contains only the sell transactions.

Expected result:

```
     Type   Trigger   Buy ID  BuyTrigger
ID   
11   buy     AA       ---     --- 
12   buy     BB       ---     ---
13   sell    ---      11      AA
14   sell    ---      12      BB
```

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use apply and df.loc to get the answer. Here's how I would do it.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[11,12,13,14],
                   'Type':['buy','buy','sell','sell'],
                   'Trigger':['AA','BB','---','---'],
                   'Buy_ID':['---','---',11,12]}).set_index('ID')
df["BuyTrigger"] = df['Buy_ID'].apply(lambda x: df.loc[x,'Trigger'] if x != '---' else np.NaN)
print (df)
```

Output of this is:

```
    Type Trigger Buy_ID BuyTrigger
ID                                
11   buy      AA    ---        NaN
12   buy      BB    ---        NaN
13  sell     ---     11         AA
14  sell     ---     12         BB
```

Instead of np.NaN, you can also give '---'. Then the answer will be:

```
    Type Trigger Buy_ID BuyTrigger
ID                                
11   buy      AA    ---        ---
12   buy      BB    ---        ---
13  sell     ---     11         AA
14  sell     ---     12         BB
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a code snippet that should do what you want:

```
import pandas as pd

def handle(data):
    buy = data[data["Type"]=="buy"][["ID", "Trigger"]]
    df = data.merge(buy, left_on="Buy ID", right_on="ID", how="left", suffixes=("", "_"))
    df = df.drop(["ID_"], axis=1).rename(columns={"Trigger_": "BuyTrigger"})
    return df

data = pd.DataFrame({
    "ID": [11,12,13,14],
    "Type": ["buy", "buy", "sell", "sell"],
    "Trigger": ["AA", "BB", "", ""],
    "Buy ID": ["", "", 11, 12]
})
result = handle(data)
```

It works by:

1. Selecting the rows containing the buy information.
2. Merging the tables to find the corresponding sell for each buy.
3. Deleting/renaming the columns per your description.

Comment: I think this is too complicated. There is an easier way to do this using apply and df.loc